# I am running into an error attempting to render a .rdl report in my .NET Core 3.1 API

Tags: c#, .net, reporting, asp.net-core-3.1

I am having an issue implementing `Microsoft.Reporting.NETCore`. I am working with .NET Core 3.1 and I am trying to get a SSRS report hosted on a Sharepoint server. However, when the code attempts to set the report parameters, or when it attempts to render the report, I get this error:

> System.MethodAccessException: Attempt by method 'Microsoft.Reporting.NETCore.SoapReportExecutionService.get_Service()' to access method 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.MonitoredScope.New(System.String)' failed.
>
> at Microsoft.Reporting.NETCore.SoapReportExecutionService.get_Service()
> at Microsoft.Reporting.NETCore.SoapReportExecutionService.SetExecutionId(String executionId)
> at Microsoft.Reporting.NETCore.ServerReport.ApplyExecutionIdToService(IReportExecutionService service)
> at Microsoft.Reporting.NETCore.ServerReport.get_Service()
> at Microsoft.Reporting.NETCore.ServerReport.EnsureExecutionSession()
> at Microsoft.Reporting.NETCore.ServerReport.SetParameters(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
> at LPWebAPICore.Models.ReportGeneratorModel.GetReportBytes(String ReportPath, ReportParameter[] Params) in C:\Users\jhutchings\source\repos\LPWebAPICore\LPWebAPICore\LPWebAPICore\Models\ReportGeneratorModel.cs:line 319
> at LPWebAPICore.Models.ReportGeneratorModel.GenerateReport(String ReportPath, String[] ParamNames, String[] ParamValues) in C:\Users\jhutchings\source\repos\LPWebAPICore\LPWebAPICore\LPWebAPICore\Models\ReportGeneratorModel.cs:line 279
> at LPWebAPICore.Controllers.ReportGeneratorController.PrintReport(String Report, String Printer, String[] ParamName, String[] ParamValue) in C:\Users\jhutchings\source\repos\LPWebAPICore\LPWebAPICore\LPWebAPICore\Controllers\ReportGeneratorController.cs:line 73

I am building the server report as such, And I am attempting to set the parameters and render the report using this code

```
public ServerReport GetReportViewer(string reportPath)
{
    ServerReport report = new ServerReport
        {
            ReportServerCredentials = {
                NetworkCredentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
            },
            ReportServerUrl = new Uri(GetReportServerURL()),
            ReportPath = $"{reportPath}"
        };

    return report;
}

private byte[] GetReportBytes(string ReportPath, ReportParameter[] Params = null)
{
    ServerReport rv = GetReportViewer(ReportPath);

    if (Params == null) 
        return rv.Render("PDF");

    rv.SetParameters(Params);
    rv.Refresh();

    return rv.Render("PDF");
}
```

Comment: Microsoft never made a report viewer for .NET Core. What is `Microsoft.Reporting.NETCore` ?

Comment: https://github.com/lkosson/reportviewercore

Comment: You're getting an exception deep inside an open source project. Have you tried searching the Github repo for any matching issues? Or opening an issue there?

Comment: Or indeed, as this open source, just set your debugger settings to 'break when exception is thrown' and you'll see exactly what the problem is.